# I don't understand this Mercurial branching

Tags: mercurial, repository, branching-and-merging, dvcs

A coworker ended up with the Mercurial history shown below (cropped screenshot from TortoiseHg). Being pretty new to Hg, neither of us understands what's going on. How is it that the rightmost sequence has a branch name varying over time? Unfortunately, I don't know the exact process by which he ended up like this, let alone how to sort this out.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it that the rightmost sequence has a branch name varying over time?

Easy. Everybody can change branch, on which will refer the next commit, use any amount branches and switch between them.

I, personally, can't see **now** any reasons for pure linear history with changing branches (for current DAG merging 356 into mainline will merge all ancestors from all parent's branches), but - WIP is WIP... and I *can expect* at least rebasing two named branches into some (new) branchpoint and branch-names of changesets will help to identify in this case content of diverged histories

Comment: I guess I'm understanding how to read the graph correctly. I thought that a chain of commits linked visually by a line in the graph _is_ a branch (whether named or unnamed), so that's how I don't understand how the branch name changes in a linear sequence of nodes. If the lines between the nodes don't show the continuity of a branch, then what do they show?

Comment: @DisplayName - parent(s)|child(s) relations. Branch (in common case) is just additional permanent metadata, added to every changeset

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the coworker forgot to update to WIP before committing. It was fun teasing apart the changes so default is clean from the ones that were supposed to be in WIP only. Had to use a bunch of strip and graft.